# Malloc an array of structs.

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I am still learning C and have run into some trouble while trying to malloc structures. I have the following structure:

```
struct data {
int *ref; 
int *port;
char data[MAX_STRING];
}temp, valid, invalid;
```

I intend on using the 'temp' struct to store input data before it is validated, then dependent on the outcome of the validation the struct will be copied to a member of either the valid or invalid array of structs.

```
int main(){
   char inputfile[100];
   FILE *file; = fopen("file.txt" , "r");

   if (file != NULL){
      read_file (file);
   }

   else{
    // Some code here..
   }

   return 0;
}  

void read_file(FILE *file)
{

char buf[1024];

   while(!feof (file))
   {
       struct temp *p_temp = malloc(sizeof(temp));

       p_temp->ref = malloc(sizeof(int));         <<<<<<< 'dereferencing pointer to incomplete type'
       p_temp->port = malloc(sizeof(int));        <<<<<<< 'dereferencing pointer to incomplete type'
       p_temp->data = malloc(sizeof(MAX_STRING)); <<<<<<< 'dereferencing pointer to incomplete type'

       fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file); 

       sscanf(buffer, "%d.%d.%s", p_temp->ref, p_temp->port,  p_temp->data);

       validate();

     }
}
```

Have I gone about using malloc the correct way with the temporary structure? I am getting the error 'dereferencing to incomplete type'

How would I then go about creating an array of valid and invalid structures that are malloced? Would I create a function such as:

```
vaild* vaild_record(){

struct vaild *p_vaild = malloc(sizeof(vaild));
if ( p_vaild == NULL)

{
    // some code here
}

p_vaild->ref= malloc(sizeof(int));
p_vaild->port = malloc(sizeof(int));
p_vaild->data =(char)malloc(sizeof(STRINGMAX);

if ( p_vaild->ref == NULL || p_vaild->port == NULL || p_vaild->data == NULL)
{
   // some code here
}

return 0;
}
```

Im a bit confused about the whole thing. Any clarity would be great thanks.

Comment: why do you do this `p_vaild->data =(char)malloc(sizeof(STRINGMAX);`? it does not make sense

Comment: Your code contains internal inconsistencies the compiler should be able to catch much earlier...

Comment: on a side note you missed an 'fclose(file)' after you have read the file (and if file != NULL) ofcourse.

Comment: Do not use `feof()` like this.  Instead test result of `fgets()`, when `NULL`, exit loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the way you declared the struct it should be

```
struct data 
{
    int *ref; 
    int *port;
    char data[MAX_STRING];
};
```

and then you do

```
struct data *p_valid;
p_valid = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
```

another thing is

```
p_valid->data = malloc(sizeof(STRINGMAX));
```

is wrong because `data` is not a pointer. And `sizeof(STRINGMAX)` is wrong too, since `STRINGMAX` seems to be a macro and hence it will expand to it's value say if you have `#define STRINGMAX 4` then it would expand to `sizeof(4)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help iharob I have amended my program but am unsure of how to malloc the char array. I now have trying it this way : temp->data = (char[STRINGMAX])malloc(sizeof(char)); gives me the error 'cast specifies array type' and trying it any other way gives me the error 'incompatible types when assigning to type char[50] from type char. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You simply don't need to.

Comment: Okay thanks, do I need to malloc any of the structure fields then?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, please don't ask another question in the comments, ask a new one. For instance, what do you want to store in the `ref` field? It it is an integer value then it should be declared as `int ref` and you wont need malloc. If it is an integer array, it is correctly declared and you will need `malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int))`. Read the `malloc` manual.

Answer (score 1):

```
Your definition of the struct:

struct data {
    int *ref; 
    int *port;
    char data[MAX_STRING];
}temp, valid, invalid;

should be more like this:

struct data 
{
    int *ref; 
    int *port;
    char data[MAX_STRING];
};

then define the arrays similar to this:

struct data temp;

struct data* valid = NULL;
struct data* invalid = NULL;
int currentValidSize = 0;
int currentInvalidSize = 0;
struct data * validTemp = NULL;
struct data * invalidTemp = NULL;

then, each time the code needs room for (another) instance of a struct

struct data *validTemp = realloc(valid, (currentValidSize+1)* sizeof(data) );
if( NULL == validTemp )
{ // realloc failed
    perrof( "realloc failed" );

    // free everything, close files, etc here probably be writing a sub function
    // and calling it here.
    // a sub function that: 
    // that walks the valid and invalid arrays, 
    // first free'ing any malloc'd fields
    // then finally free'ing the whole array

    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, realloc successful

// update array size counter
currentValidSize++;

// update ptr to valid array of structs
valid = validTemp;
validTemp = NULL;

similar for adding an entry to the invalid array of structs

then update the valid array of structs from temp as:
(note the '-1' in the offset into valid[])

memcpy( &valid[currentValidSize-1], &temp, sizeof data );
// Note you will also have to perform a 'deep' copy of any areas 
// that were malloc'd within the 'temp' struct
```

Answer (score -1):

From just a quick look, I think your problem may be where you are mallocing in the read_file function. You should have`malloc(sizeof(struct temp))`.

Also casting the malloc wouldn't hurt.

Also there is no need for the `temp, valid, invalid` at the end of the struct, just use `struct data`

Hope this helps

Comment: casting `malloc` is necessary in C++ because of the way `void` is treated in C++, but in C it is absolutely not necessary.